# Loading js multiple times – Chrome problem

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am trying to use external js file to load content in divs.

The js file needs to be loaded as much as divs loaded.
For example:

```
<div class="classname1" userId="101010" unitId="111"></div>
<script src="//example.com/js/thefile.js"></script>

<div class="classname2" userId="101010" unitId="222"></div>
<script src="//example.com/js/thefile.js"></script>

<div class="classname2" userId="101010" unitId="333"></div>
<script src="//example.com/js/thefile.js"></script>
```

This code will be provided to the users to embed it in their websites. Say, it would be embeded in example2.com and example3.com.

When the js loads at thise sites, the code reads the attributes and depending on them it shows the related content inside the div.

The script works fine in Firefox (eg: if there are 3 pieces of embed code, then the browser shows 3 contents), but it doesn't work well on Chrome (it shows one content only).

As I noted that, Chrome detects the number of js loads, for example 3 times, however the first piece of code works and the other pieces doesn't.

Note: when I used a trick it worked in Chrome, but I don't want to use this easy solution: I changed the src url for each embed code by adding ?v=1 , ?v=2 and ?v=3 after the .js file.

Any ideas for solving this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: You can create one script, that load scripts js when load window end, example: 

```window.onload =  function() {
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = '//example.com/js/thefile.js';
document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Actually, that's probably _not true_.  The js _probably_ could be reconstructed so that it's loaded ONCE, and the script(s) that need to trigger on that element are triggered multiple times.... but you've not provided enough info to solve this.

Answer (score 4):

The real problem here isn't that the file wasn't loaded 3 times, rather it's that the code wasn't executed three times.

Browsers are expected to cache the files. And, you can expect inconsistent behaviour around what happens when same file's included more than once. Using a nonce, like v1 etc will disable caching. The best thing to do here would be wrap the functionality of your JS file in a function, and then load the file only once. You can simply call the function three times, or as many times as required.